# Community mathematics or Mathematics community?

Tags: adjectives, sentence-structure

Which of the following is more suitable as a title for a base forum for people who love to deal with mathematics:

> 1. Community mathematics

> 2. Mathematics community

Comment: And I'd like to get some [context, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: "Mathematics community" if *probably* what you want, but I can definitely imagine some scenario where community mathematics is a thing.

Comment: Yes, there is no "answer" without more context, because both could be correct. Even though you most likely want "Mathematics community" like user8399 said.

Comment: Now I wrote the context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They can both be correct but mean different things. So it depends what you are trying to say.

In "community mathematics", "community" is modifying "mathematics" - so we are talking about "mathematics of the community kind" or  "mathematics that we do together as a community".

In "mathematics community", "mathematics" is modifying "community". We are talking about "the community which gets together to do mathematics".

In the English language if you have two nouns together, the first one is always acting as a modifier for the second one.

Comment: Not ***always***, but almost always, yes. Exceptions are generally formulaic (Mount St. Helens, Castle MacBeth), especially for certain types of place names.